# How to remove list element(s) existing in another list in Java?

Tags: java, list, element

I have

```
List<String> listOne = new ArrayList<String>();
listOne.add("3");
listOne.add("11");
listOne.add("20");`
```

and

```
List<String> listTwo = new ArrayList<String>();
listTwo.add("1");
listTwo.add("2");
listTwo.add("3");
listTwo.add("6-11");
listTwo.add("18-20");
```

I want to remove from `listTwo` elements that exists in `listOne`. In this example values that should be removed are: `3`, `6-11` and `18-20`. `6-11` because in `listOne` we have value `11` and the same for `18-20`.

Could you help me please to do it if it is possible? I don't know how to resolve it. This is not the same as in others, because of its remove rules. Otherwise the other answers from another similar questions doesn't give me the solution.

Comment: Do you really mean that you are storing closed ranges in the list? It sounds like it would be more appropriate to be storing instances like `new Range(18, 20)`, for example, in the list, rather than Strings.

Comment: Since these are lists of `String`, do you mean to remove any value from `listTwo` where a value from `listOne` is a substring, e.g. using `contains()`?

Comment: If these are supposed to be numbers and number ranges, don't use `String`. Also, if you're removing `11` from `6-11`, shouldn't that become `6-10`?

Comment: @Andreas yes, as you can see even if the listTwo has another value with value 6, it have to be removed (6-11) as in the listOne we have value 11.
Many thanks for your reply

Comment: @AndyTurner Sorry Andy I dont know how to treat it with your suggestion, any example please?Many thanks for your reply

Comment: So if listTwo has `6-11` and listOne has `9`, does that mean remove range `6-11`, or does that do nothing because `9` is not mentioned in listTwo?

Comment: @Andreas No, if it is 6-11 so it should be removed as it is, 6-11. It comes as a string in the application. If listTwo does not have listOne's values, so nothink will be removed.

Comment: Should `6-11`remove `9`? If that is the case then do not store them as Strings, it would be a pretty hefty operation.

Comment: I believe @AndyTurner is referring to a range class such as [`IntRange`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/math/IntRange.html) from the Apache Commons Lang library.

Comment: @Emz No, if listTwo does not have listOne's value, nothink will be removed.

Comment: Not so elegant may be, but iterating over 2 lists and creating a 3rd refined one may help, based on matches.

Comment: @AnindaBhattacharyya Could you provide an example please ?Thanks in advance

Comment: @Andreas sure, that'd work, but I wasn't advocating that class in particular. I'm simply saying that storing things in strings is more work than it needs to be, because you have to parse the ints out of it, as well as guarding against you passing in `"Foo"` to one or other of the lists.

Comment: If list one has 6 and list two has 6-11, will it be going to remove 6-11 in list two?

Comment: @LahiruJ Yes, if listOne has 11 or 6 (doesn't matter) so the value 6-11 will be removed.

Comment: See for reference one of the non-elegant, but working ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments indicate that only explicitly listed values should cause element to be removed, e.g.:

```
listOne    listTwo             Action
"1"        "1", "3-9", "11"    remove "1", but not "11"
"2"        "1", "3-9", "11"    do nothing
"3"        "1", "3-9", "11"    remove "3-9"
"4"        "1", "3-9", "11"    do nothing (3-9 is not a range)
```

So, with that weird logic, here's an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // should remove 3, 6-11, 18-20
    System.out.println(remove(Arrays.asList("3", "11", "20"),
                              new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "6-11", "18-20"))));
    // should remove 2, not remove 6-11 (not a range), and not remove 18-20 (8 is not 18, 2 is not 20)
    System.out.println(remove(Arrays.asList("2", "8"),
                              new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "6-11", "18-20"))));
}
private static List<String> remove(List<String> listOne, List<String> listTwo) {
    for (Iterator<String> listIter = listTwo.iterator(); listIter.hasNext(); ) {
        String value = listIter.next();
        if (shouldRemove(value, listOne))
            listIter.remove();
    }
    return listTwo; // for easy of use
}
private static boolean shouldRemove(String value, List<String> listOne) {
    int idx = value.indexOf('-');
    if (idx == -1) {
        for (String ref : listOne)
            if (ref.equals(value))
                return true;
    } else {
        String value1 = value.substring(0, idx);
        String value2 = value.substring(idx + 1);
        for (String ref : listOne)
            if (ref.equals(value1) || ref.equals(value2))
                return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

*Output*

```
[1, 2]
[1, 3, 6-11, 18-20]
```

Comment: This example works more correctly. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> listOne = new ArrayList<String>();
    listOne.add("3");
    listOne.add("11");
    listOne.add("20");

    List<String> listTwo = new ArrayList<String>();
    listTwo.add("1");
    listTwo.add("2");
    listTwo.add("3");
    listTwo.add("6-11");
    listTwo.add("18-20");

    List<String> thirdList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String secondItem : listTwo) {
        boolean match = false;
        for (String firstItem : listOne) {
            if(secondItem.contains(firstItem)) {
                match = true;
            }
        }
        if(!match) {
            thirdList.add(secondItem);
        }
    }
    for (String string : thirdList) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: If listOne has a `"1"` element, this code would remove `"1"`, `"6-11"`, and `"18-20"`. I don't believe (guessing here) that OP wants that.

Comment: Good point, the problem can be modified simply by splitting over - and compare then. Awaiting confirmation before making the edit.

Comment: That is what I assumed, and implemented in my answer. As you said, we'll see what OP really wants, after another 500 questions to elicit whatever that might be.

Comment: You are right, if listOne has element 1 it removes all element contains value 1 :) but it will not be correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> listOne = new ArrayList<>();
        listOne.add("3");
        listOne.add("11");
        listOne.add("20");

        List<String> listTwo = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
        listTwo.add("1");
        listTwo.add("2");
        listTwo.add("3");
        listTwo.add("6-11");
        listTwo.add("18-20");

        listOne.stream().forEach(value -> {
        listTwo.stream().filter(value2 -> (value2.contains(value))).forEach(value2 -> {
            String[] minMax = value2.split(value2);
            if (minMax.length == 1 && value2.equals(value)) {
                listTwo.remove(value2);
            } else if (minMax.length == 2) {
                int intValue2 = Integer.parseInt(value2);
                int min = Integer.parseInt(minMax[0]);
                int max = Integer.parseInt(minMax[1]);
                if (intValue2 >= min && intValue2 <= max) {
                    listTwo.remove(value2);
                }
            }
        });
        });

        listTwo.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

[Lambda Filtering Collections](http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/java-8-lambda-tutorial/filter-tutorial.php)

[What is CopyOnWriteArrayList?](http://java67.blogspot.be/2012/09/what-is-copyonwritearraylist-in-java-example-vs-arraylist.html)

Comment: If listOne has a `"1"` element, this code would remove `"1"`, `"6-11"`, and `"18-20"`. I don't believe (guessing here) that OP wants that.

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: And it's still not clear if members of `listTwo`, containing a strip, represent a disc (an interval) or just two different numbers...

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<String> listOne = new ArrayList<String>();
    listOne.add("3");
    listOne.add("11");
    listOne.add("20");
    List<String> listTwo = new ArrayList<String>();
    listTwo.add("1");
    listTwo.add("2");
    listTwo.add("3");
    listTwo.add("6-11");
    listTwo.add("18-20");

   List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();     // to store matched Strings

   for (String s : listTwo) {
        String strs[] = new String[2];
        if (s.contains("-")) {
            strs = s.split("-");                 // check for Strings
        }
        if (listOne.contains(s) 
               || listOne.contains(strs[0]) 
               || listOne.contains(strs[1])) {
            values.add(s);                       // save the value to a list
        }

    }
    listTwo.removeAll(values);
```